# Electron vue scaffold throwing errors

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

I generated the electron-vue scaffold with the vue-cli using `vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue`
After running `yarn` I started the application with `yarn run dev`. By default I get these errors:

```
? Electron -------------------

  Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/189cf481-dd71-43bf-be88-90673ee0aae1

  For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

? ----------------------------

? Electron -------------------

  [10928:0911/182704.656:ERROR:CONSOLE(7323)] "Extension server error: Operation
 failed: : has no execution context", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled
/inspector.js (7323)

? ----------------------------

? Electron -------------------

  [10928:0911/182705.653:ERROR:CONSOLE(7323)] "Extension server error: Operation
 failed: : has no execution context", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled
/inspector.js (7323)

? ----------------------------

? Electron -------------------

  [10928:0911/182706.654:ERROR:CONSOLE(7323)] "Extension server error: Operation
 failed: : has no execution context", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled
/inspector.js (7323)

? ----------------------------
```

On top, the application takes almost 30 seconds to load. Before that I just see the Electron / Chrome Debugger window but they are not filled with any content.
This loading behavior is still given when I use `yarn build` to create and run the packaged electron application.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Best place to get an answer for this is in the official [Vue chat](https://chat.vuejs.org/) #desktop-app channel. SimulatedGreg hangs out there.

Comment: Are you using electron-packager or electron-builder?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well. Some people fixed it by closing running proxy processes that occupied localhost. Another temporary solution is to delete node modules and run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

The electron-vue is not being updated at this time. (currently, electronic version 2.x)

There's a boilerplate that I forked the electron-vue and updated all the modules with the latest modules. The use method is the same and we have added the ui framework and css-precessor.

- Electron 5
- Vue-CLI 3
- Babel 7
- Vue 2.6
- css-preprocessor

  - Sass
  - Less
  - Stylus
- UI Framework

  - Quasar 1.x
  - Vuteify 2.x

We recommend you try it.

https://github.com/kdydesign/vue-electron5

Answer (score 0):

The long loading time for Electron turned out to be my Home Directory being mapped to a network drive, missing on startup because I was in da different network. Electron seems to wait 30 seconds for a timeout when trying to read the home directory (in order to load application settings !?)